# Azure cognitive search custom analyzer fail in the index json

Tags: json, azure, azure-cognitive-search

Im trying to add custom analyzer so the search won't split string like b-1-d to 3 tokens when using search.isMatch in $filter param.

The thing is when I'm creating the index it doesn't let me to add the custom analyzer because missing odataType, tried different ways to spell it but not working.
[image: Here is a screenshot from what I've noticed]

also when trying to use that custom one in the field analyzer it throws me the following:

[image]

What do you suggest doing?

Thanks

Ps
Went over the issues reported here and didn't find a solution to that, also the documentation didn't quite help.

Comment: Thank you for reporting this issue. It has been fixed with the latest deployment version 118666261.20240213.1.